# Hide file extension via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently use the following code to hide the extension on website pages via htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)/([^/]+)(\?.*)?$
RewriteCond %1/%2.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/([^/]+)(\?.*)?$
RewriteRule .* %1/%2.php [QSA]
```

That way I can access the site like this: **mysite.com.br/page**, when the file name is page.php.

The problem is that if I put a slash at the end **mysite.com.br/page/** it gives error 404. How can I fix this?

From what it seems to me he tries to search for a folder when he puts the bar at the end, how can I fix it? It is not a folder but a file.

Comment: use `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]` and test.

Comment: Not worked, error 404 continues :/

Comment: Is it possible to comment disable other rules and test this one?

Comment: Yes, which ones should i disable?

Comment: Disable `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)/([^/]+)(\?.*)?$
RewriteCond %1/%2.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/([^/]+)(\?.*)?$  RewriteRule .* %1/%2.php [QSA]` and test.

Comment: Disabled, now i received Internal Server Error